# Show $\bigcap_{p \in (1, \infty)} (\frac{1}{p}, 3p) \subseteq [1,3]$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> $\bigcap_{p \in (1, \infty)} (\frac{1}{p}, 3p) \subseteq [1,3]$

My first intuition is to prove the contrapositive instead. That being:

$x \notin [1,3] \Rightarrow x \notin \bigcap_{p \in (1, \infty)} (\frac{1}{p}, 3p)$

Meaning if we can find at least one $p$ where $x$ isn't a member of $(\frac{1}{p}, 3p)$, then the proof is complete.

Am I on the right track here?

Comment: Yes, you are. ${}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that for $p,q\in(1,\infty)$ with $p<q$, we have $$\left(\frac{1}{p},3p\right)\subset
\left(\frac{1}{q},3q\right)$$
because for $1<p<q$, $$\frac{1}{q}<\frac{1}{p}\qquad\text{and}\qquad 3p<3q$$
thus the collection $\left\{\left(\frac{1}{p},3p\right)\right\}_{p\in(1,\infty)}$ is a nested collection of intervals, therefore
$$ \bigcap_{p\in(1,\infty)}\left(\frac{1}{p},3p\right)=(1,3)\subset [1,3]$$

Answer (score 0):

This question is about proving the following:

If $a$ and $b$ are given real numbers, and $a<b+\epsilon $ for all $\epsilon >0$, then $a\leq b$. This can be prove by contrapositive as you suggested.

Suppose $b<a$, and take $\epsilon =\frac{a-b}{2}$. Then by assumption $a< b+\epsilon= \frac{a+b}{2}$. Which means $a<b$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Option:

$A_p:=(1/p,3p)$ , $p>1$.

$A_p \subset A_q$ for $p<q$.

1) $(1,3)\subset A_p$ , $p>1$.

$(1,3)\subset \cap_{p>1} A_p$;

2)$\cap_{p>1}A_p \subset (1,3)$.

Let $x \in \cap_{p>1}A_p$ then

$x$ in every $A_p$ , $p>1$, i.e.

$x$ in every $(1/p,3p)$ , $p>1$;

$1/p<x<3p$, for all $p>1$, i e.

$x \in (1,3)$.

3) $\cap_{p>1}A_p =(1,3)\subset [1,3]$.